# Where to download IE9 for Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to do some testing (at work! In life, I'm a Mac) of older browsers, but Microsoft has removed all of their IE9 download links for Windows 7.

I.e. when I go to the [IE download page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17621/internet-explorer-downloads), I'm notified that:

> If you’re running Windows 7, the latest version of InternetExplorer [sic]
>   that you can install is Internet Explorer 11.

Does anyone know of somewhere else I might download this precious gem of a piece of <s>poop</s> software?

Comment: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_internet_explorer_9.html

Comment: That's it!  Verified virus free and functional!  Now after two computer restarts (one to uninstall IE11, another to install IE9) I've now time traveled five years into the Internet Explorer past!  Thank you kindly @magicandre1981

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft removed IE9 for Windows 7 from their download center, but I was able to find an [installer on majorgeeks](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_internet_explorer_9.html). Download the x64 installer from [here](http://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/get/microsoft_internet_explorer_9,2.html) and install the `IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe`.

Comment: This site redirects to the Microsoft Web site for download. However, the IE9 installer was removed from there, so the redirect no longer works. :(

Comment: @pvgoran I found the file here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/the1/files/IE/IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe/download

Comment: Right, I eventually found it there, too. :)
Good thing they have digital signatures, so we can be sure they are indeed original files from MS.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx

It has got:

**Windows Internet Explorer 9 for IT Professionals and Developers--Windows Vista 64-bit Edition and Windows Server 2008 64-bit Edition**

**Windows Internet Explorer 9 for IT Professionals and Developers--Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008**

Comment: this is the IE9 for Vista, he uses Windows 7 ;)

Comment: Very true @magicandre1981!!  It seems we've all been guilty of this at one time or another; you can't understand the reqs without doing the research. A friendly reminder to read the question!!  :-)